# Validate remote JSON than parse it

Tags: c#, json, jsonp, json.net

I am using **NewtonSoft.Json** parser for parsing remote URL.

My remote JSON example as below

```
Kerberos.load({"todays" : "Fri, Mar 15",
    "datas" : [
            {
                "id" : "2021200303"
            }
            ]});
```

I am parsing JSON example as below

```
using (var WebClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    WebClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    var _Json = WebClient.DownloadString(_MyJsonRemoteURL_);

    _Json = _Json.Replace("Kerberos.load(", "");
    _Json = _Json.Replace("]});", "]}");

    dynamic _Dynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_Json);
    foreach (var _JsonNode in _Dynamic.datas)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_JsonNode.SelectToken("id").ToString());
    }
}
```

So, is there any way to validate remote JSON string, without using **Replace** method?

Comment: Except that's not valid JSON, it's JSONP.

Comment: @svick thank you. Dou you have any suggestion for parsing JSONP

Answer (score -2):

It's very much possible if you want to do it for JSON, check out [Contract testing a json service in .net](http://stacktoheap.com/blog/2012/10/31/contract-testing-a-json-service-in-net/)

cross posting the code here for quick reference, more detail checkout the link

```
[Test]
public void ShouldBeAbleToValidateTheJSONServiceResponseForFunctionalityA()
{
    const string schemaJson = @"
{
    'description': 'Service Response',
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'product': {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'availability': {
                        'type': 'array',
                        'items': {
                                    'type': 'object',
                                    'properties': {
                                                    'Local': { 'type' : 'number'},
                                                    'Storehouse': { 'type' : 'number'},
                                                } 
                                }
                    }
            }        
        }
    }
}";
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", 1 }, { "city", "Chennai" } };
    AssertResponseIsValidSchema(schemaJson, parameters);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question: parsing JSONP.

Comment: @svick yes I agree initially I thought it for JSON only after answering I realized that its for JSONP